# php array values as constants

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

Constants variables are defined as:

```
define('MENU_HOME', 'Úvod');  //slovak
define('MENU_HOME', 'Home');  //english
```

---

### QUESTION:

How to output array from:

```
$menu_items = array ('MENU_HOME', 'MENU_ABOUT', 'MENU_CONTACT');
```

to

```
$menu_items = array (MENU_HOME, MENU_ABOUT, MENU_CONTACT);
```

Comment: edited to more obvious form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `define('MENU_HOME', 'Úvod');` is not global variable, but constant. To get its value by name stored in string, you can use [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function.